# Why is the base class and derived class constructor getting called when creating object of the child class

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

```
Code : 
   class A
    {
        public A()
        {

        }

    }

    class B : A
    {
        public B()
        {

        }
    }

    class C : B
    {
        public C()
        {

        }
     }
Main()
{
C a =new C();
}
```

When creating a new object C, first the class A constructor is called, then the class B constructor, then finally the class C constructor. Suppose I do not want to use any variable of class A in child C. Why is the base class constructor getting called?

Comment: Because `B` _is_ `A` the base class must be initialized even if you don't want to use anything from it. How should the runtime know? Feel free to let the constructor of `A` be empty.

Comment: This is just how it works in C#. By default the base class constructor is called. You shouldn't have side effects in constructors because of that.

Comment: @Mafii: Why base class constructor is getting called by default

Comment: @sudhir its defined like this in the language specification - and it makes sense in the end. An object can only be of a type if it has been constructed so it has to run the base constructor to be able to be used from that type.

Comment: @sudhir "Suppose I do not want to use any variable of class A in child C" -  you never know, not even if it is like this, the base class exists so it has to be initialized. Its like this in all C-Like languages.

Comment: @Mafii: I want to know why it's defined like in this  language.

Comment: @sudhir Think of it as you can't have a cat, that isn't born like an mammal.

Answer (score 1):

Your base class constructors are being called because you've derived the child classes from the base classes. By definition the child classes inherit the member variables and functions of their base class. You should probably read up more on how object oriented inheritence works.

Let's take an example. Say you in your program you are dealing with people. You create a people class with a constructor and member variables name, age, and gender. You can instantiate this into as many people as you want.

Then you want further functionality in your program and you create two new classes, one for Students, and one for Employees.

With students, you want name, age, gender, grade, major and year and with Employees you want name, age, gender, position, salary.

The two new classes: Students and Employees are derived from the Person class because they need name, age, and gender.

If you do not want the class C to have it's base class created all you need to do is not have class C inherit class B.

There is plenty of information on Google on derived classes and how they work. https://www.google.ca/?gws_rd=ssl#q=inheritance+in+object+oriented+programming